# Printing a wchar_t gives weird output

Tags: c, printf, wchar-t, format-specifiers

Running this code snippet:

```
wchar_t *wstr = L"áßå®";
wprintf(L"%s",wstr);
```

gives the output:

> «

instead of

> áßå®

I am new to `wchar_t`. How do I get the expected output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not very sure, but did you try `%ls`?

Comment: As you can read [HERE](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/) format for wchar is `%ls` not `%s`

Comment: Wrong format specifier results in undefined behavior.

Comment: `L"áßå®";` might not be supported by your compiler.  The compiler does not have to support embedded unicode characters in your source.  It only has to support ASCII.  Try encoding your string like `wchar_t *wstr = L"\uE1\uDF\uE5";`

Comment: Another possible problem is that the output terminal doesn't support unicode

Comment: I think the latter could be the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

I believe, you need to change your code

```
 wprintf(L"%s",wstr);
```

to

```
wprintf(L"%ls",wstr);
```

Ref: From `C11` standard, chapter §7.29.2.1, emphasis mine

> **l (ell)**
>  Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int argument; that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a long int argument; that a following c conversion specifier applies to a wint_t argument; **that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t` argument;** or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier.

Comment: Changing the format specifier to L"%ls" does not result to any change. The output remains: «